# angularJs ng -Repeat over an array of json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is the format of json which I need to parse:

```
[{
  "perAddress": {
    "city": "Delhi",
    "Street": "saket",
    "pin": "101011"
  },
  "flag": false
}, {
  "perAddress": {
    "city": "Delhi",
    "Street": "malvya",
    "pin": "101011"
  },
  "flag": true,
  "alterAddress": {
    "city": "bangalore",
    "street": "velondore",
    "pin": "560103"
  }
}];
```

1. If the flag is false then the corresponding row will not be
   highlighted and only `perAddress` will be populated .
2. If the flag is true then the corresponding row will be highlighted with
   containing `perAddress` and on click on the row the `alterAddress` need
   to populated. How to iterate through the json?

Comment: You can use `.forEach` method which accepts as argument a callback function.

Comment: use angular.Foreach

Comment: It seems json is not valid, or might be with last edit somebody just altered.

Comment: Format of json is not correct,it may be:[
   {
    "perAddress": {
    "city": "Delhi",
    "Street": "saket",
    "pin": "101011"
   },
   "flag": false
 }, {
     "perAddress": {
      "city": "Delhi",
        "Street": "malvya",
        "pin": "101011"
     },
  "flag": true,
  },{
    "alterAddress": {
    "city": "bangalore",
    "street": "velondore",
    "pin": "560103"
  }
 }];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you in 2 ways. No need of using flag too.

```
.highlight {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Using flag solution follows:

```
 <div>
   <div ng-repeat="address in addresses" ng-class="{'highlight' : address.flag}">
    <a ng-if="!showAlterAddress" ng-click="showAlterAddress = !showAlterAddress">{{address.perAddress}}</a>
    <span ng-if="showAlterAddress">{{address.alterAddress}}</span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Without using flag solution follows:

```
 <div>
   <div ng-repeat="address in addresses" ng-class="{'highlight' : address.alterAddress}">
    <a ng-if="!showAlterAddress" ng-click="showAlterAddress = !showAlterAddress">{{address.perAddress}}</a>
    <span ng-if="showAlterAddress">{{address.alterAddress}}</span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "perAddress": {
      "city": "Delhi",
      "Street": "saket",
      "pin": "101011"
    },
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "perAddress": {
      "city": "Delhi",
      "Street": "malvya",
      "pin": "101011"
    },
    "flag": true,
    "alterAddress": {
      "city": "bangalore",
      "street": "velondore",
      "pin": "560103"
    }
  }];


});
```

```css
.Highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="d in data" ng-init="" ng-click="d.flag = !d.flag" ng-class="{'Highlight' : d.alterAddress}">
    <li>{{d.perAddress}}
      <div ng-if="d.alterAddress">
        <div ng-if="!d.flag">{{d.alterAddress}}</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a css class "Highlight" and use this code -

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="i in jsonArray" ng-class="{'Highlight' : i.flag}">
    <span>{{i.perAddress.city}} | {{i.perAddress.Street}} | {{i.perAddress.pin}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```